# Radiation mutation breeding in plant seeds: practical aspects

Tags: botany, mutations, radiation

I did read some seed irradiation papers and they all use Gy as unit of measure, however I have never seen seed weights reported.

How did they calculate that, since Gy is J/kg?

Differencies aside between using gamma and X-rays, is there any equivalent dose I can apply using an X-ray tube fitted with a dose area product meter?

I am not sure if I can assume that spreading seeds in an area and then irradiating up to a certain dose area product would mean that each of those seeds was exposed to a certain amount of radiation.

Suggestions welcome, thank you.

Comment: It might help if you shared a link to one of the papers you're talking about. I don't work with seeds, but I wouldn't expect to see the actual weights reported since the unit is already normalized to weight. For example, if I'm reporting on arsenic concentrations in the liver, I'm analyzing the normalized data in units like ng of arsenic per gram of tissue, and my methods section describes how those values were calculated prior to analysis. I would imagine that whoever makes the instruments used for irradiating seeds have standard protocols available online.

Comment: I see. So should I assume that they weighted the seeds and irradiated until they reached a certain amount of J/kg, hence being Gy?

Comment: Here are some links: http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTotal-JXNY200709006.htm https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:41095572 https://www.actahort.org/books/1067/1067_9.htm

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't have to assume things when reading a scientific research article. They should include some indication of the methodology or protocols used. Saddly, that's often not the case. I'd try reaching out by email to the corresponding author on a paper your interested in and politely requesting their protocol. Most people are usually willing to help. You could also try contacting the manufacturer of the instrument you are working with for support. Sorry this didn't really answer your question.